How to secure a backup server when i send data via ssh
When I backup another server, I put my private key on the server to be able to send with ssh the data I want to backup.
But if a hacker compromises my server they will also be able to access the backup.
Is there a solution against that?

It depends on what you mean by "access":

Read: Doesn't matter, if the hacker can read your private key then they can read "live" files on the server anyway.

Create (fake backups?): Doesn't matter much, and probably impossible to prevent when the attacker can tamper with real files and let the normal backup procedure find them.

Delete: The only important kind of access that you need to prevent.


One way to prevent backup deletion is to limit that SSH key to only be able to talk a special backup protocol, e.g. Borg 1.x can be set up in a "append only" mode (although I'm not sure if this will exist in Borg 2).
I would configure the backup server to make periodic ZFS or Btrfs snapshots of the backup storage – the hacker may delete the backups via SSH but you can just restore them from yesterday's snapshot.
If the server doesn't have a snapshot-capable filesystem, you can also set up a cronjob to automatically chown/chmod the older backups so that they become read-only or outright inaccessible for the "backup" SSH user.
(Of course, this all assumes that your backup SSH key is for a limited account and not root. If your backup procedure connects to your backup server as root, start with don't do that.)

Append mode exists in borg 2.x; changes since 1.x were "internal", like repository format, code base, etc, but from outside it looks pretty much the same. Also, I want to point out, that even if connection is made as root but using key which is heavily restricted, it's safe, and it's actually a single case when I can accept using root connection.

@NikitaKipriyanov: The recent "borgstore" announcement which added SFTP support (which is a fairly significant external change) did seem to threaten that the server-side process would be removed, not just made optional.

Well, it's fairly recent and also sad indeed, the ability to make backups immutable to the system which is being backed up was one of the reasons for borg to be a backup system of a choice...
